# ¿Cómo acceder a Microsoft Access por medio de Python usando pyodbc?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

Quiero imprimir la información de una un archivo de Microsoft Access pero aparece el siguiente error:

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\javie\Documents\Programas\be.mdb;')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especificó ningún controlador predeterminado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Lo que ejecuto es:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\javie\Documents\Programas\be.mdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from Productos")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Quiero sacar los datos de la tabla Productos.

Comment: Veo que usas un fichero .mdb, ¿has probado a quitar del Driver el *.accdb?

Comment: No lo había hecho, gracias